# GitKit - How to enable users to link Facebook as an additional provider to an existing password account

Tags: facebook, google-identity-toolkit

We have Google Identity Toolkit implemented on our server and can successfully create "simple password accounts" and "Facebook accounts".

However if a user has first signed in with "simple password account", created password, confirmed email, etc...

How can this user then at a later time add Facebook as an alternative provider?

In our case, if this user clicks "Sign in" he will see:
[image: GitKit widget popup after sign in button]

On the following login screen however, he can only choose the existing "simple password account".. if he does, the login proceeds to password input, without a chance to use Facebook as an alternative.

What do we have to configure so that the user has the possibility at any time to link another provider to his "simple password account"?

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Google recommends to ask in SO, but then they do not care much it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down to the Account Linking section in this [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/federated-login#ios_and_android).

The key phrase here is ***Thus if Google Identity Toolkit detects that the same email address was used at both identity providers, we link the two accounts.*** It appears this is not something you can do manually, and accounts can only be linked in this particular situation. In the case of Facebook I believe the email to which they are referring would be the primary email found in the Facebook user settings.

I hope they implement more comprehensive account linking in the future! The Gitkit account manager would be the ideal place to do this if you are listing Google.